# CUDA Dynamic Parallelism Deferencing Global Memory

Tags: cuda, dynamic-parallelism

To test out dynamic parallelism, I wrote a simple code and compiled it on GTX1080 with the following commands.

```
nvcc -arch=sm_35   -dc dynamic_test.cu -o dynamic_test.o
nvcc -arch=sm_35   dynamic_test.o  -lcudadevrt -o dynamic_test
```

However, the output is not as expected. It seems like the pointers passed to the child kernel are de-referenced.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

__global__ void child(int *a, int *b, int *c){

        int tid = threadIdx.x;
        c[tid] = a[tid] + b[tid];
}


__global__ void Parent(int *a, int *b, int *c){

        int tid = threadIdx.x;
        const int n = 10;

        a[tid] = tid;
        b[tid] = 2*tid;
        c[tid] = -10;

        __syncthreads();
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        if (tid == 1){
          child<<<1,n>>>(a,b,c);
          cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        }
}


int main(){

        int *d_a, *d_b, *d_c;
        const int n = 10;
        int a[n],b[n],c[n],i;

        cudaMalloc((void**)&d_a,n*sizeof(int));
        cudaMalloc((void**)&d_b,n*sizeof(int));
        cudaMalloc((void**)&d_c,n*sizeof(int));

        Parent << < 1, n >>> (d_a,d_b,d_c);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        cudaMemcpy(a,d_a,n*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        cudaMemcpy(b,d_b,n*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        cudaMemcpy(c,d_c,n*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
           printf("a[%d] = %d\n",i,a[i]);
        }
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
           printf("b[%d] = %d\n",i,b[i]);
        }
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
           printf("c[%d] = %d\n",i,c[i]);
        }

        cudaFree(d_a); cudaFree(d_b); cudaFree(d_c);

        return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
a[0] = 1
a[1] = 0
a[2] = 4208446
a[3] = 0
a[4] = 0
a[5] = 0
a[6] = 0
a[7] = 0
a[8] = 0
a[9] = 0
b[0] = 3
b[1] = 0
b[2] = 4204323
b[3] = 0
b[4] = 4205312
b[5] = 0
b[6] = 4732449
b[7] = 0
b[8] = 4205680
b[9] = 0
c[0] = 194906208
c[1] = 32767
c[2] = 4204143
c[3] = 0
c[4] = 4205616
c[5] = 0
c[6] = 4732608
c[7] = 0
c[8] = 4231155
c[9] = 0
```

Reading from the programming guide, I should be able to pass global variables to child kernels without causing any deferencing. I am not sure why the output is incorrect. My ultimate goal is using the cublas library from within kernels. Any suggestion in that direction will also be helpful.

Comment: Is this also your first CUDA program? Do you know that your CUDA installation is working correctly? Because I have compiled and run your code and it works as expected. What happens if run it using cuda-memcheck?

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to that direction. It is now working with cuda 8.0.

Answer (score -2):

The problem was solved by switching from cuda 7.5 to cuda 8.0.

Comment: When I ran your code, I used CUDA 7.5, so the version was not the problem.

Comment: I am running this code on a cluster because I have no access to those graphics cards otherwise. It could be that the installation for 7.5 is incorrect. However, I am not even sure if that's the case because other cuda programs without dynamic parallelism compile and run fine.